# Sending email via GmailApp as HTML to retain signature & image

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a project where i need to bulk send an email with text specific to each user, and with the signature and image from the associated gmail account. I've got this atm:

```
//get template/draft email & body
const scGmailTemplate = GmailApp.getDraft("r4329894329375089160");
const scGmailTemplateMessage = scGmailTemplate.getMessage();
const scGmailTemplateBody = scGmailTemplateMessage.getBody();

//create new gmail
let scGmailContactMessageBody = scGmailTemplateBody;

//create array for gmail find & replaces [find, replace]
const gmailFindReplace = [["INV_START", scVars.INV_START],
                          ["INV_END", scVars.INV_END],
                          ["DEM_DATE", scVars.DEM_DATE]
                         ];

gmailFindReplace.forEach(x=>{scGmailContactMessageBody=scGmailContactMessageBody.replace(x[0], x[1])});

const scGmailSubject = "Service Charge Invoice ("+scVars.INV_START+"-"+scVars.INV_END+")";

let bodyHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(scGmailContactMessageBody);//didnt work

GmailApp.sendEmail("me@me.com", "test", scGmailContactMessageBody);
```

Issue is the resultant email is just the raw html with the image displayed at the bottom

I've tried adding `{htmlBody: html}` as an option but that throws an error `html not defined`.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `htmlBody` expects a string.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("me@me.com", "test", scGmailContactMessageBody, {htmlBody: scGmailContactMessageBody});
```

No need for `let bodyHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(scGmailContactMessageBody);` as `getBody()` already returns an HTML string.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the key. Setting `{htmlBody: scGmailContactMessageBody}` all is well

Answer (score 1):

From  the question

> I've tried adding `{htmlBody: html}` as an option but that throws an error `html` not defined.

The error message is straight forward, the code doesn't include an statement declaring `html`

try replacing `html` by `bodyHtml`